# Minimize the space between <a> link lines, when the a link text spanes on multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to show an image and under the image to show `<a>` link as follow:-

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left:8px;max-width:185px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="******/9854/production/_103969983_gettyimages-939175472.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px">
<a target="_blank" style="line-height:5px" href="https://*********-45937924">
World's longest sea crossing: ******** ****** bridge opens</a>
</span></div>
```

Here is the result:-

[image]

Now the problem i am facing is that i need to minimize the space between the `<a>` lines. i tried to add `line-height:5px` but it did not have any effect.so can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Comment: reduce `line-height` in `<a>`

Comment: @NikhilKinkar i define it as `1px` instead of `5px` but did not have any effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height` does not affect directly elements with `display:inline` such as is the default with spans and anchor links.

> The line-height CSS property sets the amount of space used for lines, such as in text. On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)</sup>

**Option 1**

Apply the `line-height` to the div

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 9px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

span {
  background: pink;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>
<a target="_blank" href="https://*********-45937924">
World's longest sea crossing: ******** ****** bridge opens</a>
</span></div>
```

Or **Option 2**

Set the span to `display:inline-block`

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

span {
  background: pink;
  font-size: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>
<a target="_blank" href="https://*********-45937924">
World's longest sea crossing: ******** ****** bridge opens</a>
</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `display: block` or `display:inline-block;` when you trying `line-height` work perfectly with `inline` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="float: left;margin-left:8px;max-width:185px">
<img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="******/9854/production/_103969983_gettyimages-939175472.jpg" alt="ntitle">
<br>
<span style="font-size:9px">
<a target="_blank" style="line-height:5px; display:inline-block;" href="https://*********-45937924">
World's longest sea crossing: ******** ****** bridge opens</a>
</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a **<p>** tag:

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left:8px;max-width:185px">
   <img style="height:90px;width:185px" src="******/9854/production/_103969983_gettyimages-939175472.jpg" alt="ntitle">
   <br>
   <span style="font-size:5px">
      <a target="_blank" style="line-height:5px" href="https://*********-45937924">
          <p>World's longest sea crossing: ******** ****** bridge opens</p>
      </a>
   </span>
</div>
```

Now the line-height style will work